# How to get record data with AudioKit without storing it in the file

Tags: record, audiokit

I want to record audio with AudioKit. What I want to achieve is a buffer with 512 bytes if the buffer is full. It will translate the buffer info through TCP. And the current situation is that I only know how to restore the Audio data into a file like in the code below.

Can anyone provide some tips to achieve my goal?

Here is my code:

```
AKAudioFile.cleanTempDirectory()        
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium

    do {
        try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
    } catch {
        AKLog("Could not set session category.")
    }

    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
    micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)

    micBooster.gain = 0

    recorder = try?AKNodeRecorder.init(node: micMixer)

    if let file = recorder.audioFile {
        print(file.directoryPath)
        player = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
    }
    player.isLooping = true

    moogLadder = AKMoogLadder(player)

    mainMixer = AKMixer(moogLadder, micBooster)

    AudioKit.output = mainMixer

    let clipRecoder = AKClipRecorder(node: mainMixer)

    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
    }
    try! recorder.record()
```